# Laravel docker compose php container always need to down and up, if route or view changed

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have **docker compose** setup for Laravel which mounted as a volume to the container. When I change view or a route, I always have to down and up docker compose to reflect the changes. I assume this is because Laravel cache. **SSH in to php container** and clear cache (*php artisan cache:clear*) also not working is my problem. I'm mounting my local code folder to container as a volume.

```
version: '3'

services:
  vue_dev:
    image: **************-public-frontend-develop:unstable
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - ENVIRONMENT=local
      - VUE_BUILD_PUBLIC_PATH=/
      - VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL=localhost/api
      - VUE_APP_STORAGE_BASE_URL=/api/storage/
    volumes:
      # Path to your vue project.
      - ../projects/sparkfore-tools-frontend:/app
    networks:
      - sparkfor

  api:
    image: **************public-backend:nightly
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    user: "${PUID}:${PGID}"
    volumes:
      - '/data/projects/backend:/app:delegated'
      - '/data/projects/backend/storage:/app/storage:delegated'
    environment:
      - AUTO_MIGRATE=false
      - APP_ENV=local
      - APP_URL=http://localhost/api
      - DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
      - DB_HOST=postgres
      - DB_PORT=5432
      - DB_DATABASE=******
      - DB_USERNAME=******
      - DB_PASSWORD=******
    networks:
      - sparkfor

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=laravel
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=*******
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    networks:
      - sparkfor

volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
  api-data:
    driver: local
networks:
  sparkfor:
    driver: bridge
```

"api" is the Laravel docker service. I tried delegated storage folder as well.

Comment: Which operating system are you running on your host machine (which OS do you run docker desktop/daemon on ?)

Comment: @TjadClark host machine is a linux one. Ubuntu 20

Comment: Interesting, then I would think that it is the Laravel process that is not hot reloading code changes.

You can try to "restart" your container (instead of down/up), which may make the process slightly faster.  

The Laravel container would have to be setup to do hot reloading to achieve what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's OPCache can sometimes cache the compiled PHP files. If OPCache is enabled, any changes to PHP files won't be immediately recognized because PHP will still be using the cached version.
To temporarily disable OPCache during development, add these lines to your php.ini:

docker-compose.yml

```
environment:
  PHP_INI_OPCACHE_ENABLE: "0"
  PHP_INI_OPCACHE_REVALIDATE_FREQ: "0"
```